# Tensorflow loaded model outputing list of `False` instead of embeddings

Tags: python, tensorflow

## **Background Information**

I have downloaded a pretrained face-detection model (13.6mb) which outputs the bounding box of the detected face. However, I don't need a face detection model, I need a model that calculates embeddings for a face. So I want to extract the layer from the face detection model which outputs the embeddings.

`main.py`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load the pretrained face detection model

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("RFB")

# make a new model which only calculates embedddings
# layer 187 outputs a 1D-tensor of length 4420, which I assumed to be the layer that outputs the embeddings

new_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.layers[187].output)

## load image

image = cv2.imread("image.jpg", cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image = cv2.resize(image, (240, 320))

## convert to batch format

image = np.array(image).reshape((1, 240, 320, 3)).astype(np.float32)

# predict

print(new_model.predict(image)[0])
```

For context, here is the output of `model.summary()`, which is the original face detection model:

```
Model: "functional_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 240, 320, 3  0           []
                                )]

 basenet.0.0_padding (ZeroPaddi  (None, 242, 322, 3)  0          ['input_1[0][0]']
 ng2D)

 basenet.0.0_conv (Conv2D)      (None, 120, 160, 16  432         ['basenet.0.0_padding[0][0]']    
                                )

 basenet.0.1_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 120, 160, 16  64         ['basenet.0.0_conv[0][0]']       
 tion)                          )

 basenet.0.2_relu (ReLU)        (None, 120, 160, 16  0           ['basenet.0.1_bn[0][0]']
                                )

 basenet.1.0_padding (ZeroPaddi  (None, 122, 162, 16  0          ['basenet.0.2_relu[0][0]']       
 ng2D)                          )

 basenet.1.0_dconv (DepthwiseCo  (None, 120, 160, 16  144        ['basenet.1.0_padding[0][0]']    
 nv2D)                          )

 basenet.1.1_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 120, 160, 16  64         ['basenet.1.0_dconv[0][0]']      
 tion)                          )

 basenet.1.2_relu (ReLU)        (None, 120, 160, 16  0           ['basenet.1.1_bn[0][0]']
                                )

 basenet.1.3_conv (Conv2D)      (None, 120, 160, 32  512         ['basenet.1.2_relu[0][0]']
                                )

 basenet.1.4_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 120, 160, 32  128        ['basenet.1.3_conv[0][0]']
 tion)                          )

 basenet.1.5_relu (ReLU)        (None, 120, 160, 32  0           ['basenet.1.4_bn[0][0]']
                                )

 basenet.2.0_padding (ZeroPaddi  (None, 122, 162, 32  0          ['basenet.1.5_relu[0][0]']
 ng2D)                          )

 basenet.2.0_dconv (DepthwiseCo  (None, 60, 80, 32)  288         ['basenet.2.0_padding[0][0]']
 nv2D)

 basenet.2.1_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 60, 80, 32)  128         ['basenet.2.0_dconv[0][0]']
 tion)

 basenet.2.2_relu (ReLU)        (None, 60, 80, 32)   0           ['basenet.2.1_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.2.3_conv (Conv2D)      (None, 60, 80, 32)   1024        ['basenet.2.2_relu[0][0]']

 basenet.2.4_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 60, 80, 32)  128         ['basenet.2.3_conv[0][0]']
 tion)

 basenet.2.5_relu (ReLU)        (None, 60, 80, 32)   0           ['basenet.2.4_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.3.0_padding (ZeroPaddi  (None, 62, 82, 32)  0           ['basenet.2.5_relu[0][0]']
 ng2D)

 basenet.3.0_dconv (DepthwiseCo  (None, 60, 80, 32)  288         ['basenet.3.0_padding[0][0]']
 nv2D)

 basenet.3.1_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 60, 80, 32)  128         ['basenet.3.0_dconv[0][0]']
 tion)

 basenet.3.2_relu (ReLU)        (None, 60, 80, 32)   0           ['basenet.3.1_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.3.3_conv (Conv2D)      (None, 60, 80, 32)   1024        ['basenet.3.2_relu[0][0]']

 basenet.3.4_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 60, 80, 32)  128         ['basenet.3.3_conv[0][0]']
 tion)

 basenet.3.5_relu (ReLU)        (None, 60, 80, 32)   0           ['basenet.3.4_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.4.0_padding (ZeroPaddi  (None, 62, 82, 32)  0           ['basenet.3.5_relu[0][0]']
 ng2D)

 basenet.4.0_dconv (DepthwiseCo  (None, 30, 40, 32)  288         ['basenet.4.0_padding[0][0]']
 nv2D)

 basenet.4.1_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 30, 40, 32)  128         ['basenet.4.0_dconv[0][0]']
 tion)

 basenet.4.2_relu (ReLU)        (None, 30, 40, 32)   0           ['basenet.4.1_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.4.3_conv (Conv2D)      (None, 30, 40, 64)   2048        ['basenet.4.2_relu[0][0]']

 basenet.4.4_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 30, 40, 64)  256         ['basenet.4.3_conv[0][0]']
 tion)

 basenet.4.5_relu (ReLU)        (None, 30, 40, 64)   0           ['basenet.4.4_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.5.0_padding (ZeroPaddi  (None, 32, 42, 64)  0           ['basenet.4.5_relu[0][0]']
 ng2D)

 basenet.5.0_dconv (DepthwiseCo  (None, 30, 40, 64)  576         ['basenet.5.0_padding[0][0]']
 nv2D)

 basenet.5.1_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 30, 40, 64)  256         ['basenet.5.0_dconv[0][0]']
 tion)

 basenet.5.2_relu (ReLU)        (None, 30, 40, 64)   0           ['basenet.5.1_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.5.3_conv (Conv2D)      (None, 30, 40, 64)   4096        ['basenet.5.2_relu[0][0]']

 basenet.5.4_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 30, 40, 64)  256         ['basenet.5.3_conv[0][0]']
 tion)

 basenet.5.5_relu (ReLU)        (None, 30, 40, 64)   0           ['basenet.5.4_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.6.0_padding (ZeroPaddi  (None, 32, 42, 64)  0           ['basenet.5.5_relu[0][0]']
 ng2D)

 basenet.6.0_dconv (DepthwiseCo  (None, 30, 40, 64)  576         ['basenet.6.0_padding[0][0]']
 nv2D)

 basenet.6.1_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 30, 40, 64)  256         ['basenet.6.0_dconv[0][0]']
 tion)

 basenet.6.2_relu (ReLU)        (None, 30, 40, 64)   0           ['basenet.6.1_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.6.3_conv (Conv2D)      (None, 30, 40, 64)   4096        ['basenet.6.2_relu[0][0]']

 basenet.6.4_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 30, 40, 64)  256         ['basenet.6.3_conv[0][0]']
 tion)

 basenet.6.5_relu (ReLU)        (None, 30, 40, 64)   0           ['basenet.6.4_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.7.branch2.0_conv (Conv  (None, 30, 40, 8)   512         ['basenet.6.5_relu[0][0]']
 2D)

 basenet.7.branch2.0_bn (BatchN  (None, 30, 40, 8)   32          ['basenet.7.branch2.0_conv[0][0]'
 ormalization)                                                   ]

 basenet.7.branch2.1_padding (Z  (None, 32, 42, 8)   0           ['basenet.7.branch2.0_bn[0][0]']
 eroPadding2D)

 basenet.7.branch2.1_conv (Conv  (None, 30, 40, 12)  864         ['basenet.7.branch2.1_padding[0][
 2D)                                                             0]']

 basenet.7.branch0.0_conv (Conv  (None, 30, 40, 8)   512         ['basenet.6.5_relu[0][0]']
 2D)

 basenet.7.branch1.0_conv (Conv  (None, 30, 40, 8)   512         ['basenet.6.5_relu[0][0]']
 2D)

 basenet.7.branch2.1_bn (BatchN  (None, 30, 40, 12)  48          ['basenet.7.branch2.1_conv[0][0]'
 ormalization)                                                   ]

 basenet.7.branch0.0_bn (BatchN  (None, 30, 40, 8)   32          ['basenet.7.branch0.0_conv[0][0]'
 ormalization)                                                   ]

 basenet.7.branch1.0_bn (BatchN  (None, 30, 40, 8)   32          ['basenet.7.branch1.0_conv[0][0]'
 ormalization)                                                   ]

 basenet.7.branch2.1_relu (ReLU  (None, 30, 40, 12)  0           ['basenet.7.branch2.1_bn[0][0]']
 )

 basenet.7.branch0.1_padding (Z  (None, 32, 42, 8)   0           ['basenet.7.branch0.0_bn[0][0]']
 eroPadding2D)

 basenet.7.branch1.1_padding (Z  (None, 32, 42, 8)   0           ['basenet.7.branch1.0_bn[0][0]']
 eroPadding2D)

 basenet.7.branch2.2_padding (Z  (None, 32, 42, 12)  0           ['basenet.7.branch2.1_relu[0][0]'
 eroPadding2D)                                                   ]

 basenet.7.branch0.1_conv (Conv  (None, 30, 40, 16)  1152        ['basenet.7.branch0.1_padding[0][
 2D)                                                             0]']

 basenet.7.branch1.1_conv (Conv  (None, 30, 40, 16)  1152        ['basenet.7.branch1.1_padding[0][
 2D)                                                             0]']

 basenet.7.branch2.2_conv (Conv  (None, 30, 40, 16)  1728        ['basenet.7.branch2.2_padding[0][
 2D)                                                             0]']

 basenet.7.branch0.1_bn (BatchN  (None, 30, 40, 16)  64          ['basenet.7.branch0.1_conv[0][0]'
 ormalization)                                                   ]

 basenet.7.branch1.1_bn (BatchN  (None, 30, 40, 16)  64          ['basenet.7.branch1.1_conv[0][0]'
 ormalization)                                                   ]

 basenet.7.branch2.2_bn (BatchN  (None, 30, 40, 16)  64          ['basenet.7.branch2.2_conv[0][0]'
 ormalization)                                                   ]

 basenet.7.branch0.1_relu (ReLU  (None, 30, 40, 16)  0           ['basenet.7.branch0.1_bn[0][0]']
 )

 basenet.7.branch1.1_relu (ReLU  (None, 30, 40, 16)  0           ['basenet.7.branch1.1_bn[0][0]']
 )

 basenet.7.branch2.2_relu (ReLU  (None, 30, 40, 16)  0           ['basenet.7.branch2.2_bn[0][0]']
 )

 basenet.7.branch0.2_padding (Z  (None, 34, 44, 16)  0           ['basenet.7.branch0.1_relu[0][0]'
 eroPadding2D)                                                   ]

 basenet.7.branch1.2_padding (Z  (None, 36, 46, 16)  0           ['basenet.7.branch1.1_relu[0][0]'
 eroPadding2D)                                                   ]

 basenet.7.branch2.3_padding (Z  (None, 40, 50, 16)  0           ['basenet.7.branch2.2_relu[0][0]'
 eroPadding2D)                                                   ]

 basenet.7.branch0.2_conv (Conv  (None, 30, 40, 16)  2304        ['basenet.7.branch0.2_padding[0][
 2D)                                                             0]']

 basenet.7.branch1.2_conv (Conv  (None, 30, 40, 16)  2304        ['basenet.7.branch1.2_padding[0][
 2D)                                                             0]']

 basenet.7.branch2.3_conv (Conv  (None, 30, 40, 16)  2304        ['basenet.7.branch2.3_padding[0][
 2D)                                                             0]']

 basenet.7.branch0.2_bn (BatchN  (None, 30, 40, 16)  64          ['basenet.7.branch0.2_conv[0][0]'
 ormalization)                                                   ]

 basenet.7.branch1.2_bn (BatchN  (None, 30, 40, 16)  64          ['basenet.7.branch1.2_conv[0][0]'
 ormalization)                                                   ]

 basenet.7.branch2.3_bn (BatchN  (None, 30, 40, 16)  64          ['basenet.7.branch2.3_conv[0][0]'
 ormalization)                                                   ]

 basenet.7_cat (Concatenate)    (None, 30, 40, 48)   0           ['basenet.7.branch0.2_bn[0][0]',
                                                                  'basenet.7.branch1.2_bn[0][0]',
                                                                  'basenet.7.branch2.3_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.7.convlinear_conv (Con  (None, 30, 40, 64)  3072        ['basenet.7_cat[0][0]']
 v2D)

 basenet.7.convlinear_bn (Batch  (None, 30, 40, 64)  256         ['basenet.7.convlinear_conv[0][0]
 Normalization)                                                  ']

 basenet.7.shortcut_conv (Conv2  (None, 30, 40, 64)  4096        ['basenet.6.5_relu[0][0]']
 D)

 tf_op_layer_basenet.7_mul (Ten  (None, 30, 40, 64)  0           ['basenet.7.convlinear_bn[0][0]']
 sorFlowOpLayer)

 basenet.7.shortcut_bn (BatchNo  (None, 30, 40, 64)  256         ['basenet.7.shortcut_conv[0][0]']
 rmalization)

 basenet.7_add (Add)            (None, 30, 40, 64)   0           ['tf_op_layer_basenet.7_mul[0][0]
                                                                 ',
                                                                  'basenet.7.shortcut_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.7_relu (ReLU)          (None, 30, 40, 64)   0           ['basenet.7_add[0][0]']

 basenet.8.0_padding (ZeroPaddi  (None, 32, 42, 64)  0           ['basenet.7_relu[0][0]']
 ng2D)

 basenet.8.0_dconv (DepthwiseCo  (None, 15, 20, 64)  576         ['basenet.8.0_padding[0][0]']
 nv2D)

 basenet.8.1_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 15, 20, 64)  256         ['basenet.8.0_dconv[0][0]']
 tion)

 basenet.8.2_relu (ReLU)        (None, 15, 20, 64)   0           ['basenet.8.1_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.8.3_conv (Conv2D)      (None, 15, 20, 128)  8192        ['basenet.8.2_relu[0][0]']

 basenet.8.4_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 15, 20, 128)  512        ['basenet.8.3_conv[0][0]']
 tion)

 basenet.8.5_relu (ReLU)        (None, 15, 20, 128)  0           ['basenet.8.4_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.9.0_padding (ZeroPaddi  (None, 17, 22, 128)  0          ['basenet.8.5_relu[0][0]']
 ng2D)

 basenet.9.0_dconv (DepthwiseCo  (None, 15, 20, 128)  1152       ['basenet.9.0_padding[0][0]']
 nv2D)

 basenet.9.1_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 15, 20, 128)  512        ['basenet.9.0_dconv[0][0]']
 tion)

 basenet.9.2_relu (ReLU)        (None, 15, 20, 128)  0           ['basenet.9.1_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.9.3_conv (Conv2D)      (None, 15, 20, 128)  16384       ['basenet.9.2_relu[0][0]']

 basenet.9.4_bn (BatchNormaliza  (None, 15, 20, 128)  512        ['basenet.9.3_conv[0][0]']
 tion)

 basenet.9.5_relu (ReLU)        (None, 15, 20, 128)  0           ['basenet.9.4_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.10.0_padding (ZeroPadd  (None, 17, 22, 128)  0          ['basenet.9.5_relu[0][0]']
 ing2D)

 basenet.10.0_dconv (DepthwiseC  (None, 15, 20, 128)  1152       ['basenet.10.0_padding[0][0]']
 onv2D)

 basenet.10.1_bn (BatchNormaliz  (None, 15, 20, 128)  512        ['basenet.10.0_dconv[0][0]']
 ation)

 basenet.10.2_relu (ReLU)       (None, 15, 20, 128)  0           ['basenet.10.1_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.10.3_conv (Conv2D)     (None, 15, 20, 128)  16384       ['basenet.10.2_relu[0][0]']

 basenet.10.4_bn (BatchNormaliz  (None, 15, 20, 128)  512        ['basenet.10.3_conv[0][0]']
 ation)

 basenet.10.5_relu (ReLU)       (None, 15, 20, 128)  0           ['basenet.10.4_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.11.0_padding (ZeroPadd  (None, 17, 22, 128)  0          ['basenet.10.5_relu[0][0]']
 ing2D)

 basenet.11.0_dconv (DepthwiseC  (None, 8, 10, 128)  1152        ['basenet.11.0_padding[0][0]']
 onv2D)

 basenet.11.1_bn (BatchNormaliz  (None, 8, 10, 128)  512         ['basenet.11.0_dconv[0][0]']
 ation)

 basenet.11.2_relu (ReLU)       (None, 8, 10, 128)   0           ['basenet.11.1_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.11.3_conv (Conv2D)     (None, 8, 10, 256)   32768       ['basenet.11.2_relu[0][0]']

 basenet.11.4_bn (BatchNormaliz  (None, 8, 10, 256)  1024        ['basenet.11.3_conv[0][0]']
 ation)

 basenet.11.5_relu (ReLU)       (None, 8, 10, 256)   0           ['basenet.11.4_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.12.0_padding (ZeroPadd  (None, 10, 12, 256)  0          ['basenet.11.5_relu[0][0]']
 ing2D)

 basenet.12.0_dconv (DepthwiseC  (None, 8, 10, 256)  2304        ['basenet.12.0_padding[0][0]']
 onv2D)

 basenet.12.1_bn (BatchNormaliz  (None, 8, 10, 256)  1024        ['basenet.12.0_dconv[0][0]']
 ation)

 basenet.12.2_relu (ReLU)       (None, 8, 10, 256)   0           ['basenet.12.1_bn[0][0]']

 basenet.12.3_conv (Conv2D)     (None, 8, 10, 256)   65536       ['basenet.12.2_relu[0][0]']

 basenet.12.4_bn (BatchNormaliz  (None, 8, 10, 256)  1024        ['basenet.12.3_conv[0][0]']
 ation)

 basenet.12.5_relu (ReLU)       (None, 8, 10, 256)   0           ['basenet.12.4_bn[0][0]']

 extras_convbias (Conv2D)       (None, 8, 10, 64)    16448       ['basenet.12.5_relu[0][0]']

 extras_relu1 (ReLU)            (None, 8, 10, 64)    0           ['extras_convbias[0][0]']

 extras_sep_dconv_padding (Zero  (None, 10, 12, 64)  0           ['extras_relu1[0][0]']
 Padding2D)

 extras_sep_dconvbias (Depthwis  (None, 4, 5, 64)    640         ['extras_sep_dconv_padding[0][0]'
 eConv2D)                                                        ]

 extras_sep_relu (ReLU)         (None, 4, 5, 64)     0           ['extras_sep_dconvbias[0][0]']

 reg_0_sep_dconv_padding (ZeroP  (None, 32, 42, 64)  0           ['basenet.7_relu[0][0]']
 adding2D)

 reg_1_sep_dconv_padding (ZeroP  (None, 17, 22, 128)  0          ['basenet.10.5_relu[0][0]']
 adding2D)

 reg_2_sep_dconv_padding (ZeroP  (None, 10, 12, 256)  0          ['basenet.12.5_relu[0][0]']
 adding2D)

 extras_sep_convbias (Conv2D)   (None, 4, 5, 256)    16640       ['extras_sep_relu[0][0]']

 reg_0_sep_dconvbias (Depthwise  (None, 30, 40, 64)  640         ['reg_0_sep_dconv_padding[0][0]']
 Conv2D)

 reg_1_sep_dconvbias (Depthwise  (None, 15, 20, 128)  1280       ['reg_1_sep_dconv_padding[0][0]']
 Conv2D)

 reg_2_sep_dconvbias (Depthwise  (None, 8, 10, 256)  2560        ['reg_2_sep_dconv_padding[0][0]']
 Conv2D)

 extras_relu2 (ReLU)            (None, 4, 5, 256)    0           ['extras_sep_convbias[0][0]']

 reg_0_sep_relu (ReLU)          (None, 30, 40, 64)   0           ['reg_0_sep_dconvbias[0][0]']

 reg_1_sep_relu (ReLU)          (None, 15, 20, 128)  0           ['reg_1_sep_dconvbias[0][0]']

 reg_2_sep_relu (ReLU)          (None, 8, 10, 256)   0           ['reg_2_sep_dconvbias[0][0]']

 reg_0_sep_convbias (Conv2D)    (None, 30, 40, 12)   780         ['reg_0_sep_relu[0][0]']

 reg_1_sep_convbias (Conv2D)    (None, 15, 20, 8)    1032        ['reg_1_sep_relu[0][0]']

 reg_2_sep_convbias (Conv2D)    (None, 8, 10, 8)     2056        ['reg_2_sep_relu[0][0]']

 reg_3_convbias (Conv2D)        (None, 4, 5, 12)     27660       ['extras_relu2[0][0]']

 reshape (Reshape)              (None, 3600, 4)      0           ['reg_0_sep_convbias[0][0]']

 reshape_1 (Reshape)            (None, 600, 4)       0           ['reg_1_sep_convbias[0][0]']

 reshape_2 (Reshape)            (None, 160, 4)       0           ['reg_2_sep_convbias[0][0]']

 reshape_3 (Reshape)            (None, 60, 4)        0           ['reg_3_convbias[0][0]']

 concatenate (Concatenate)      (None, 4420, 4)      0           ['reshape[0][0]',
                                                                  'reshape_1[0][0]',
                                                                  'reshape_2[0][0]',
                                                                  'reshape_3[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_strided_slice_1 (T  (None, 4420, 2)     0           ['concatenate[0][0]']
 ensorFlowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_strided_slice (Ten  (None, 4420, 2)     0           ['concatenate[0][0]']
 sorFlowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_Mul_2 (TensorFlowO  (None, 4420, 2)     0           ['tf_op_layer_strided_slice_1[0][
 pLayer)                                                         0]']

 cls_0_sep_dconv_padding (ZeroP  (None, 32, 42, 64)  0           ['basenet.7_relu[0][0]']
 adding2D)

 cls_1_sep_dconv_padding (ZeroP  (None, 17, 22, 128)  0          ['basenet.10.5_relu[0][0]']      
 adding2D)

 cls_2_sep_dconv_padding (ZeroP  (None, 10, 12, 256)  0          ['basenet.12.5_relu[0][0]']
 adding2D)

 tf_op_layer_Mul (TensorFlowOpL  (None, 4420, 2)     0           ['tf_op_layer_strided_slice[0][0]
 ayer)                                                           ']

 tf_op_layer_Exp (TensorFlowOpL  (None, 4420, 2)     0           ['tf_op_layer_Mul_2[0][0]']
 ayer)

 cls_0_sep_dconvbias (Depthwise  (None, 30, 40, 64)  640         ['cls_0_sep_dconv_padding[0][0]']
 Conv2D)

 cls_1_sep_dconvbias (Depthwise  (None, 15, 20, 128)  1280       ['cls_1_sep_dconv_padding[0][0]']
 Conv2D)

 cls_2_sep_dconvbias (Depthwise  (None, 8, 10, 256)  2560        ['cls_2_sep_dconv_padding[0][0]']
 Conv2D)

 tf_op_layer_Mul_1 (TensorFlowO  (None, 4420, 2)     0           ['tf_op_layer_Mul[0][0]']
 pLayer)

 tf_op_layer_Mul_3 (TensorFlowO  (None, 4420, 2)     0           ['tf_op_layer_Exp[0][0]']
 pLayer)

 cls_0_sep_relu (ReLU)          (None, 30, 40, 64)   0           ['cls_0_sep_dconvbias[0][0]']

 cls_1_sep_relu (ReLU)          (None, 15, 20, 128)  0           ['cls_1_sep_dconvbias[0][0]']

 cls_2_sep_relu (ReLU)          (None, 8, 10, 256)   0           ['cls_2_sep_dconvbias[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_AddV2 (TensorFlowO  (None, 4420, 2)     0           ['tf_op_layer_Mul_1[0][0]']
 pLayer)

 tf_op_layer_RealDiv (TensorFlo  (None, 4420, 2)     0           ['tf_op_layer_Mul_3[0][0]']
 wOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_RealDiv_1 (TensorF  (None, 4420, 2)     0           ['tf_op_layer_Mul_3[0][0]']
 lowOpLayer)

 cls_0_sep_convbias (Conv2D)    (None, 30, 40, 6)    390         ['cls_0_sep_relu[0][0]']

 cls_1_sep_convbias (Conv2D)    (None, 15, 20, 4)    516         ['cls_1_sep_relu[0][0]']

 cls_2_sep_convbias (Conv2D)    (None, 8, 10, 4)     1028        ['cls_2_sep_relu[0][0]']

 cls_3_convbias (Conv2D)        (None, 4, 5, 6)      13830       ['extras_relu2[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_Sub (TensorFlowOpL  (None, 4420, 2)     0           ['tf_op_layer_AddV2[0][0]',      
 ayer)                                                            'tf_op_layer_RealDiv[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_AddV2_1 (TensorFlo  (None, 4420, 2)     0           ['tf_op_layer_AddV2[0][0]',
 wOpLayer)                                                        'tf_op_layer_RealDiv_1[0][0]']

 reshape_4 (Reshape)            (None, 3600, 2)      0           ['cls_0_sep_convbias[0][0]']

 reshape_5 (Reshape)            (None, 600, 2)       0           ['cls_1_sep_convbias[0][0]']

 reshape_6 (Reshape)            (None, 160, 2)       0           ['cls_2_sep_convbias[0][0]']

 reshape_7 (Reshape)            (None, 60, 2)        0           ['cls_3_convbias[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_concat (TensorFlow  (None, 4420, 4)     0           ['tf_op_layer_Sub[0][0]',
 OpLayer)                                                         'tf_op_layer_AddV2_1[0][0]']

 concatenate_1 (Concatenate)    (None, 4420, 2)      0           ['reshape_4[0][0]',
                                                                  'reshape_5[0][0]',
                                                                  'reshape_6[0][0]',
                                                                  'reshape_7[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_Minimum (TensorFlo  (None, 4420, 4)     0           ['tf_op_layer_concat[0][0]']
 wOpLayer)

 softmax (Softmax)              (None, 4420, 2)      0           ['concatenate_1[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_Maximum (TensorFlo  (None, 4420, 4)     0           ['tf_op_layer_Minimum[0][0]']
 wOpLayer)

 concatenate_2 (Concatenate)    (None, 4420, 6)      0           ['softmax[0][0]',
                                                                  'tf_op_layer_Maximum[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_Shape (TensorFlowO  (3,)                0           ['concatenate_2[0][0]']
 pLayer)

 tf_op_layer_strided_slice_3 (T  (2,)                0           ['tf_op_layer_Shape[0][0]']
 ensorFlowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_strided_slice_2 (T  (None, 4420)        0           ['softmax[0][0]']
 ensorFlowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_Shape_1 (TensorFlo  (3,)                0           ['concatenate_2[0][0]']
 wOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_Prod (TensorFlowOp  ()                  0           ['tf_op_layer_strided_slice_3[0][
 Layer)                                                          0]']

 tf_op_layer_Shape_2 (TensorFlo  (3,)                0           ['concatenate_2[0][0]']
 wOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_Greater (TensorFlo  (None, 4420)        0           ['tf_op_layer_strided_slice_2[0][
 wOpLayer)                                                       0]']

 tf_op_layer_strided_slice_4 (T  (0,)                0           ['tf_op_layer_Shape_1[0][0]']
 ensorFlowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_concat_1/values_1   (1,)                0           ['tf_op_layer_Prod[0][0]']
 (TensorFlowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_strided_slice_5 (T  (1,)                0           ['tf_op_layer_Shape_2[0][0]']
 ensorFlowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_Reshape_1 (TensorF  (None,)             0           ['tf_op_layer_Greater[0][0]']
 lowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_concat_1 (TensorFl  (2,)                0           ['tf_op_layer_strided_slice_4[0][
 owOpLayer)                                                      0]',
                                                                  'tf_op_layer_concat_1/values_1[0
                                                                 ][0]',
                                                                  'tf_op_layer_strided_slice_5[0][
                                                                 0]']

 tf_op_layer_Where (TensorFlowO  (None, 1)           0           ['tf_op_layer_Reshape_1[0][0]']
 pLayer)

 tf_op_layer_Reshape (TensorFlo  (None, 6)           0           ['concatenate_2[0][0]',
 wOpLayer)                                                        'tf_op_layer_concat_1[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_Squeeze (TensorFlo  (None,)             0           ['tf_op_layer_Where[0][0]']
 wOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_GatherV2 (TensorFl  (None, 6)           0           ['tf_op_layer_Reshape[0][0]',
 owOpLayer)                                                       'tf_op_layer_Squeeze[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_strided_slice_6 (T  (None, 4)           0           ['tf_op_layer_GatherV2[0][0]']
 ensorFlowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_strided_slice_7 (T  (None,)             0           ['tf_op_layer_GatherV2[0][0]']
 ensorFlowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_NonMaxSuppressionV  (None,)             0           ['tf_op_layer_strided_slice_6[0][
 3 (TensorFlowOpLayer)                                           0]',
                                                                  'tf_op_layer_strided_slice_7[0][
                                                                 0]']

 tf_op_layer_GatherV2_1 (Tensor  (None, 6)           0           ['tf_op_layer_GatherV2[0][0]',
 FlowOpLayer)                                                     'tf_op_layer_NonMaxSuppressionV3
                                                                 [0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_Shape_3 (TensorFlo  (2,)                0           ['tf_op_layer_GatherV2_1[0][0]']
 wOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_strided_slice_8 (T  ()                  0           ['tf_op_layer_Shape_3[0][0]']
 ensorFlowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_strided_slice_9 (T  (None,)             0           ['tf_op_layer_GatherV2_1[0][0]']
 ensorFlowOpLayer)

 tf_op_layer_Minimum_1 (TensorF  ()                  0           ['tf_op_layer_strided_slice_8[0][
 lowOpLayer)                                                     0]']

 tf_op_layer_TopKV2 (TensorFlow  [(None,),           0           ['tf_op_layer_strided_slice_9[0][
 OpLayer)                        (None,)]                        0]',
                                                                  'tf_op_layer_Minimum_1[0][0]']

 tf_op_layer_GatherV2_2 (Tensor  (None, 6)           0           ['tf_op_layer_GatherV2_1[0][0]',
 FlowOpLayer)                                                     'tf_op_layer_TopKV2[0][1]']

==================================================================================================
Total params: 281,100
Trainable params: 276,292
Non-trainable params: 4,808
```

`model.layers[187]` which I used as the output for `new_model` refers to this layer: `tf_op_layer_Greater (TensorFlowOpLayer)`

Also, here is the structure of the directory `RFB`:

```
.
└── RFB/
    ├── variables/
    │   ├── variables.data-00000-of-00001
    │   └── variables.index
    └── saved_model.py
```

## **Problem**

This is the output I get from running `main.py`:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:SavedModel saved prior to TF 2.5 detected when loading Keras model. Please ensure that you are saving the model with model.save() or tf.keras.models.save_model(), *NOT* tf.saved_model.save(). To confirm, there should be a file named "keras_metadata.pb" in the SavedModel directory.
WARNING:tensorflow:No training configuration found in save file, so the model was *not* compiled. Compile it manually.
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 617ms/step
Prediction: [False False False ... False False False]
```

The prediction is indeed a list of length `4420`, but I expected the values to be floating point numbers, not `False`.

Comment: Why would you think that a layer called `tf_op_layer_Greater` (referring to a comparison operation, `>`) is the embedding layer? Your assumption that index 187 is the embedding index must be wrong.

Comment: I just assumed it was the embedding layer because it was the first layer to output a 1D tensor. I'm probably wrong though...